# Cucumber report generation doesn't work. Please provide me jenkins pipeline and Cucumber runner code part

Tags: cucumber, reporting, karate

I want integrate Karate with. And I use Jenkins Pipeline. Please provide me Cucumber options which can help me to generate Cucumber Report. This is my steps to Generate Cucumber report in Jenkins pipeline.

```
                       steps {
                           fileIncludePattern: "**/cucumber.json",
                           jsonReportDirectory: "target"
                       }
                   }
```

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json"})
```

I see this error message in jenkins

```
[CucumberReport] Using Cucumber Reports version 5.0.2
[CucumberReport] JSON report directory is "target"
[CucumberReport] Copied 0 json files from workspace "C:\workspace\workspace\MS_Tests\Accounts_Service_Tests\target" to reports directory "C:\Jenkins\jobs\MS_Tests\jobs\Accounts_Service_Tests\builds\43\cucumber-html-reports\.cache"
[CucumberReport] Copied 0 properties files from workspace "C:\workspace\workspace\MS_Tests\Accounts_Service_Tests\target" to reports directory "C:\Jenkins\jobs\MS_Tests\jobs\Accounts_Service_Tests\builds\43\cucumber-html-reports\.cache"
[CucumberReport] Processing 0 json files:
[CucumberReport] Missing report result - report was not successfully completed
[CucumberReport] Build status is changed to UNSTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Karate does not support the `Cucumber` annotation or even the `format` options any more. I think you need to read the docs and understand this properly.

Link: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution

So that will get you the "Cucumber JSON". Once you have that, adding that to Jenkins is a standard thing.